# Barcode Scanner with excel export

Tags: java, mysql, database, excel, barcode-scanner

I have a project with Barcode scanner where i have to scan Barcode which will give a string with a special character on scanning Barcode on the material and after getting these these string i have to insert them in database on regular interval and lastly to get excel export option where all the string values will be displayed in excel.

Can Anyone guide me that what approach should i have for this.  I am building it on Java platfrom.

I know this is relatively off-topic, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the Question is too tough to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bar code scanners used with computers usually just output some numbers and an enter. Like a keyboard.

Start with a program that can read things from the keyboard, and then save them to a database.

Create another program that exports the database content to either csv or an excel file for instance with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).